# Object synchronization exception only when using breakpoints, in F#

Tags: f#, thread-synchronization

I get this error:

```
Unhandled exception. System.Threading.SynchronizationLockException: Object synchronization method was called from an unsynchronized block of code.
   at System.Threading.Monitor.Exit(Object obj)
```

With this code:

```
        this.UpdateTimer <-
            let interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0.5)
            new Timer(TimerCallback(fun x ->
                (
                    try
                        if Monitor.TryEnter(UpdateLock) then
                            try
                                let response = RestClient.Execute(Request)
                                response |> ignore
                            with ex ->
                                Logging.Error(printfn "%s" ex.Message)
                    finally
                        Monitor.Exit(UpdateLock)
                )
            ), new Object(), int interval.TotalMilliseconds, int interval.TotalMilliseconds)
```

But this happens *only* when I put a breakpoint on the RestClient.Execute call.
The RestClient is RestSharp, as this is not an async call, so the call from the timer should stay on the same thread.

Is there an obvious problem with the code? or could it be a debugger issue, where it resumes the execution on another thread?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error throws when you try to exit a lock object you never entered.

You have to write `Monitor.Exit(UpdateLock)` when you **definetely** entered the `Monitor.TryEnter(UpdateLock)`.

This can be achieved when you turn the exit into the `if` like:

```
if Monitor.TryEnter(UpdateLock) then
    try
        try
            let response = RestClient.Execute(Request)
                response |> ignore
        with ex ->
            Logging.Error(printfn "%s" ex.Message)
    finally
        Monitor.Exit(UpdateLock)
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: ahh, I didn't realize what happened: as long as things ran at normal speed, it worked because I always entered; when I caused a delay, by hitting a breakpoint, it would fail as it never entered.. yes, the logic flow was wrong.. I was focused on my first f# try/catch/finally and wrote it wrong. Thanks for seeing it!